# Instagram API: Get posts from a certain user that also has a certain hashtag

Tags: php, api, instagram

I know of these two endpoints: `/users/{user-id}/media/recent` and `/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent`

But I'm trying to get only posts by a certain user that also have a certain hashtag. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Currently I'm using the [Instagram PHP API](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) library, doing something like this:

```
require 'vendor/Instagram-PHP-API/instagram.class.php';
$api = new Instagram('API KEY');

// Get Hashtag Search
$result = $api->getTagMedia('somehashtag', 4); // This brings me back the last 4 posts by any user :/   

// Store in a local file for JS consumption
$json = json_encode($result);
$file = TEMPLATEPATH . '/js/instagrams.json';
$fh = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $json);
fclose($fh);
```

Anyone know of an *easy* way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, just getting it down somewhere incase anyone else is trying to do the same thing.

```
require 'vendor/Instagram-PHP-API/instagram.class.php';
$api = new Instagram('API KEY'); // Client ID

// Get Recent Search
$result = $api->getUserMedia('THE USER ID', 20);
$data = $result->data;

$newresult = new stdClass();
$newdata = array();


foreach($data as $index=>$instagram) {
    if (in_array('somehashtag', $instagram->tags)) {
        array_push($newdata, $instagram);
    }
}

$newresult->data = $newdata;

$json = json_encode($newresult);
$file = TEMPLATEPATH . '/js/instagrams.json';
$fh = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $json);
fclose($fh);
```

So `$newresult` is my new object that only has posts from the specified user with the specified hashtag.